# How to find the deleteHash of an inserted image hosted on imgur?

Tags: support, images, uploader, imgur

When I edit an answer I have used the toolbar to insert an image, that is hosted on imgur then. As found in this Q&A [Imgur delete anonymous upload (Greenshot)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39671271/5014688) there is presented a **deleteHash** that can be used to delete the anonymous upload on imgur.

Where do I find this **deleteHash**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't find it. When you use Stack Exchange's image uploader, you're not communicating directly with imgur; your browser makes a POST call to https://meta.stackexchange.com/upload/image?method=json (or an equivalent URL on the site you're on) and this is what you get back:

```
{"Success":true,"Error":0,"UploadedImage":"https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwmRo.jpg"}
```

There's no `deleteHash`; it could be that Stack Exchange saves it somewhere in their own database, since they're able to delete images, e.g. in response to [DMCA takedown requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy). But it could also be that they just send the URL of the image, since they have a special contract with imgur (that's why images are hosted on `i.stack.imgur.com` instead of `i.imgur.com`).

This makes some sense; everything you write or upload here is subject to the [Terms of Service](https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing) which state this:

> #### Subscriber Content
>
> You agree that any and all content, including without limitation any and all text, graphics, logos, tools, photographs, images, illustrations, software or source code, audio and video, animations, and product feedback (collectively, “Content”) that you provide to the public Network (collectively, “Subscriber Content”), is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Overflow on a worldwide, royalty-free, non-exclusive basis pursuant to Creative Commons licensing terms (CC BY-SA 4.0), and you grant Stack Overflow the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to access, use, process, copy, distribute, export, display and to commercially exploit such Subscriber Content, even if such Subscriber Content has been contributed and subsequently removed by you

Being able to delete the image yourself would contradict this.

Comment: OK, but changing and improving an image, the old version isn't linked anymore and just digital waste. I would like to avoid this.

Comment: That is very noble of you @Ingo , but [storage is cheap](https://wiki.c2.com/?StorageIsCheap)

Comment: A wastebasket is also cheap, but I do not purchase a new one when it is full. How do you get the message `{"Success": ...}`

Comment: @Ingo you can see that in your browser's console, the Network tab